# Onload function not working?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter-3

Onload function is not working.I cannot play the song automatically when the song is loaded.Here is my view.

```
<div class="main" onload="enableAutoplay()">
    <div class="audio-name">
        <h1><?php echo str_replace('_',' ',$name);?></h1>


    </div>





        <center>
            <audio id="audio" controls="controls" >
                    <source src="<?php echo base_url();?>musics/<?php echo $name;?>"  type="audio/mp3" >

            </audio>
        </center>
        <center><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/audio/showaudio" class='back'>Back to All song list</a></center>
    </div>

<script>

            var vid = document.getElementById("audio");
        function enableAutoplay() {
            vid.autoplay = true;
            vid.load();
        }

        function disableAutoplay() {
            vid.autoplay = false;
            vid.load();
        }

        function checkAutoplay() {
            alert(vid.autoplay);
        }
</script>
```

i like to play the song when user click the song name.but here user have to click the "play" button to play the song.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `onload` event can only be used on the `body` itself, frames, images, and scripts. In other words, it can be attached to only body and/or *each external resource*. The div is not an *external resource* and it's loaded as part of the body, so the `onload` event doesn't apply there.

Answer (score 1):

as far as I know, `onload` function can be used on `<body>` tag, it doesn't seem to work on other tags. try adding it on `<body>` or just running the function in js.